# Callbacks in Python Maya plugin

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create a callback in my Maya plugin that runs every time a new object is created. The callback works but the data object passed is of NoneType. I want to access the newly created object in my callback function, how do i do that?

```
g_Callbacks = list()

def initializePlugin( obj ):
    g_Callbacks.append( OpenMaya.MEventMessage.addEventCallback( "DagObjectCreated", callback ) )

    ...

def callback( data ):
    print data.apiTypeStr()
```

Comment: Have you tried the `clientData` flag in `addEventCallback`?

Comment: I have tried:

Null = OpenMaya.MObject() and then use it in the callback as:
addEventCallback( "DagObjectCreated", callback, Null  )

but this just passes Null as the data to the callback unaltered.

Comment: Are you trying to run code every time _you_ create an object, or every time anything creates one?

Comment: Every time I create an object.

Comment: Have you tried creating an MPXCommmand and hooking it to a DagObjectCreated scriptJob?

Comment: No i have not, I have just started looking at writing Maya plugins and find it somewhat hard to go from documentation to implementation. Is it possible for you to provide an example over how this may look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like there are two separate issues.

Notificiations on object creation are 'free', in the sense that you can do this without the API by using a scriptJob.  Here's a trivial example

```
def new_object_callback():
    print "created", cmds.ls(sl=True)

cmds.scriptJob(e=('DagObjectCreated', new_object_callback))
```

The callback here is just a plain python script , but it could be a function created by an [MPXCommand](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/maya-api-programming/your-first-plug-in/) (that link is a good intro to a very simple command plugin, btw).

There is one limitation here:  the creation callback will fire once per undo block.  A menu item, button or script creates a single undo --- which means that an action which creates multiple objects will only get that notification once (and the example code above will only print out the message for the last created object).

Another way of reading the question is how to fire a callback when you create the object yourself in a plugin. That's a simpler problem, although plugins for creating objects are kind of wordy to write. (A decent intro [here](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/maya-api-programming/introduction-to-dependency-graph-plug-ins/) -- the python stuff is interleaved with C++, because the docs for all of this are still written for C++)  Every plugin node class has to have a function called `initialize`, which will be called every time the plugin creates a new node, so you can use that to call any code you need to run at startup.

OpenMaya is a real pain in the butt, since you're basically writing C++ through Python.  Here's a couple of decent references:

[http://www.amazon.com/Maya-Python-Games-Film-Reference/dp/0123785782](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123785782)
[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Programming-Python-Robert-Galanakis/dp/1849694729](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849694729)